# Missing return statement public long

Tags: java, android, return, return-type

I'm currently writing code for my final year project and I have come accross an issue that I cannot seem to fix.

I changed my public void to a public long in my DatabaseHandler (returning as id which is then used elsewhere) and since changing the code it is insisting I have a missing return statement, but I can't figure out where or why. The original code works fine but as soon as I change the public void to public long the missing return statement error appears.

The original code:

```
    public void UpdateProfileData(String email, String forename, String surname, String password, String DOB, int height, float weight, boolean gender) {
    String query = "SELECT * FROM Profile";
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);
    int count = cursor.getCount();

    if (count == 0)
    {
        //No data stored - we need to insert the row.
        db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

        values.put("Email", email);
        values.put("Forename", forename);
        values.put("Surname", surname);
        values.put("Password", password);
        values.put("DOB", DOB);
        values.put("Height", height);
        values.put("Weight", weight);
        values.put("Gender", gender);

        db.insert("Profile", null, values);

    }
    else if (count == 1)
    {
        db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

        values.put("Email", email);
        values.put("Forename", forename);
        values.put("Surname", surname);
        values.put("Password", password);
        values.put("DOB", DOB);
        values.put("Height", height);
        values.put("Weight", weight);
        values.put("Gender", gender);


        db.update("Profile", values, "Id=1", null);

    }

    else
    {
        //Something went wrong.
    }
}
```

And the new code:

```
    public long UpdateProfileData(String email, String forename, String surname, String password, String DOB, int height, float weight, boolean gender) {
    String query = "SELECT * FROM Profile";
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);
    int count = cursor.getCount();

    if (count == 0)
    {
        //No data stored - we need to insert the row.
        db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

        values.put("Email", email);
        values.put("Forename", forename);
        values.put("Surname", surname);
        values.put("Password", password);
        values.put("DOB", DOB);
        values.put("Height", height);
        values.put("Weight", weight);
        values.put("Gender", gender);

        long id = db.insert("Profile", null, values);
        return id;
    }
    else if (count == 1)
    {
        db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

        values.put("Email", email);
        values.put("Forename", forename);
        values.put("Surname", surname);
        values.put("Password", password);
        values.put("DOB", DOB);
        values.put("Height", height);
        values.put("Weight", weight);
        values.put("Gender", gender);


        long id = db.update("Profile", values, "Id=1", null);
        return id;
    }

    else
    {
        //Something went wrong.
    }
}
```

I am new to java and coding in general so if it's a silly mistake, please remember to be kind and explain in simple terms! Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: You need to return something in the `Something went wrong` case.

Comment: Start returning something from the `else` block. For Example, `return -1l;`

Comment: In addition to what @CommonsWare indicated, this code is an example of why using a single return point is often the most effective approach.

Comment: That's great, thank you all very much! Sorry for being dim, I've literally been coding for about 4 weeks max, so I have absolutely no idea what I'm doing and have approximately 2 weeks to complete my project :(

Answer (score 0):

This here:

```
else
    {
        //Something went wrong.
    }
```

is the reason of the complain...

your method should return a long no matter what... and in every if/ ifelse you are doing it right, you are missing here the return...

## HotFix:

add a return according to the logic in your app...

```
else
    {
        //Something went wrong.
     return -1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

All "paths" of a non-`void` method need a `return` statement. Your `else` case at the end is one path that does not have a `return`.

An alternative solution than simply putting a `return` inside the else is to pre-initialize the `id` and `return` at the end of the method.

```
long id = -1;

if (count == 0) {
   id = db.insert...
} else if (count == 1) {
   id = db.update...
} else {
  // Something went wrong
}

return id;
```